# Change the language in the calendar - dateTimePicker

Tags: jquery, calendar, datetimepicker

I know that there are a lot of such topics but none of them helped me ... I would like to change the language from English to Polish. I'm sending the code below.

```
$('#date-from, #date-to', form).dateTimePicker({
        paging: ['', ''],
        picker: ['date'],
        format: 'd/m/Y',
        filter: function(date){
            // Select date in the future
            var d = new Date();
            if (date.getTime()  d.getYear() || (date.getYear() == d.getYear() && date.getMonth() >= d.getMonth());
        }
    }).dateTimePickerRange();
    
    $('select', form).styleSelect({
        class_wrap: 'ul-dropdown-wrap',
    });

    var groups = $('.group', form).filter(function(){
        return !$(this).hasClass('submit');
    }).click(function(){
        $(groups).removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
    $('#name').trigger('click').trigger('focus');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I edit code in file "bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js".
I am using Japanese.

```
months: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
```

to

```
 months: ['1月', '2月', '3月', '4月', '5月', '6月', '7月', '8月', '9月', '10月', '11月', '12月']
```